# Regex for image url to validate pathfiled in cq5

Tags: regex, aem

I need to validate a pathfield for a image. Image path can be from dam (ex: /content/dam/myapp) or can be from external url (ex: http://www.test.com/test.jpg

```
\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)|^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$
```

The above one is not validating /content/dam/.

Answer (score 0):

If it is internal which mean you would get "content/dam/myapp/test.jpg" as query string then you can try something like this:

```
#content/(.*)?(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$#
```

and $1 will have dam/myapp
 For external you can write the rule on the same pattern or as a separate pattern.